# disconnecting Cygwin commands from Windows CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin, gcc, mingw

in a system im trying to use gcc installed in `c:/mingw/bin`, i also set the related PATH variable for that, but running the command `gcc -v` always shows the cygwin installed gcc because it tells **Thread model: posix**. how is it possible? where is it configured?

Comment: PATH and nothing else.  Your cygwin is in your path before the mingw.  I have found it handy to fire up cmd.exe with a batch file for each configuration.  Have the batch file add only the path variables for that system and not even have the other system in the path at all or confusion (like this) will occur.  Also.. if you can, WSL will give you the REAL versions of these tools without the crappy bloated ports.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas oh tnx, i was mistaked about PATH variable, there is two separate PATH, one is local user and other is the system, cygwin was in the system var.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas also thanks for the suggestion its realy good practice to making isolated path variables, i should try it `https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832544/5862335`

Comment: i found it relative 'https://discuss.python.org/t/could-we-add-python-to-system-path-by-default/3067/3'